# Communication Error when uploading 90 MB IPA file with Swift to AppStore

Tags: swift, xcode, upload, app-store, itmstransporter

**I've added external swift frameworks to my Objective C project.**

**IPA file size increased up to 90 Mb**.

Since that moment **I can't upload it to App Store** neither via Xcode, nor AppLoader, nor Fastlane.

After 10 minutes or more it reports on **"Verifying assets with the Appstore"** step:

**Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.
Error while processing package: XXXXXXXXX.itmsp
An exception has occurred : Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity.**

**I've tried:**

- 5 networks (2 cellular, wifi, lan without proxy),
- 2 computers other Apple computers,
- use the latest ITMSTransporter,
- Removed bitcode and uploading app's symbols for bug reporting to thin
  IPA file.

Xcode 10.1 - the latest available on my Mac Pro 2015.

Two weeks of every day uploading  - no success.
For the last 4 years of supporting my app this is the first time when I can't upload it for 2 weeks with the same error.

**Please help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after three weeks of searching the cause problem. (The last week with Apple Support Team.)

**project file .entitlements contained not used data in "Associated domains" section**:

```
<array>
    <string>applinks:XXXXXX.com</string>
</array>
```

After removing it Apple servers received my IPA.

Thank God.

Remove all unnecessary settings in .entitlements before uploading.

Carefully check all setting in .plist

After **removing unnecessary Swift code and support** 
IPA became **only 8 Mb instead of 90**.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! ❤️